# Why is this regex not allowing this text?

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I have a username validator `IsValidUsername`, and I am testing "baconman" but it is failing, could someone please help me out with this regex?

```
if(!Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^[a-zA-Z]\\w+|[0-9][0-9_]*[a-zA-Z]+\\w*$")) {
    isValid = false;
}
```

I want the restrictions to be: (It's very close)

1. Be between 5 & 17 characters long
2. contain at least one letter
3. no spaces
4. no special characters

Comment: "Be between 5 & 17 characters long" I cannot see any of that in the regex. Did you try? This is not a place for homework...

Comment: You don't code for your 5-17 characters criteria.Include that point in expression

Comment: Whoops sorry the 5-17 is taken care else where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're escaping unnecessarily: if you write your regex as starting with @ outside the string, you don't need both \ - just one is fine.

Either:

```
@"\w"
```

or

```
"\\w"
```

**Edit:** I didn't make this clear: right now due to the double escaping, you're looking for a \ in your regex and a w. So your match would need [some character]\w to match (example: "a\w" or "a\wwwwww" would match.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are best taken care of in normal C#. They don't map well to a regular expression. Just code them up using LINQ which works on strings like it would on an `IEnumerable<char>`.

Also, understanding a query of a string is much easier than understanding a Regex with the requirements that you have.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do everything as part of a Regex, however it is not pretty :-)

```
^(\w(?=\w*[a-zA-Z])|[a-zA-Z]|\w(?<=[a-zA-Z]\w*)){5,17}$
```

It does 3 checks that always results in 1 character being matched (so we can perform the length check in the end)

1. Either the character is any word character \w which is before [a-zA-Z]
2. Or it is [a-zA-Z]
3. Or it is any word character \w which is after [a-zA-Z]